# how to make .htaccess only perform redirect but do not perform rewrite after a rule matched?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have two rules in my /old/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old/(.*)? /new/$1
RewriteRule ^(page_[^/]+)[/]*$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

How to make it stop matching the second rule once the first rule is matched to redirect? I found that the new url becomes treated by both rules, e.g. .../old/page_123 -> .../new/page_123?page=123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to translate your `RedirectMatch` to `RewriteRule` and use the `L`flag to terminate after match:

```
RewriteRule /old/(.*)? /new/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(page_[^/]+)[/]*$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `[L]` at first line also

```
RedirectMatch 301 /old/(.*)? /new/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(page_[^/]+)[/]*$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```